# Update element's CSS on click using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript and have to use a function for different options but I do not know how to make it work.

```
function changecolor(){
  $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
  $(this).css('border-top', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
  $(this).css('border-right', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
}
```

I want that every time I click on the options I activate the function changecolor

```
 $('#op1').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  changecolor();
});
```

Comment: What you did is correct. Are you getting an error? Use F12 in your browser to check if there is any output in your console

Comment: changecolor does not know what do you mean by `this`

Answer (score 4):

You need to reference the event's target which is the element you clicked in that instance:

```js
$('#op1').on('click', function(e){
  changecolor(e.target);
});

function changecolor(elem){
  $(elem).css('background-color', 'red');
  $(elem).css('border-top', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
  $(elem).css('border-right', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="op1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
```

Also: you don't need to include the `e.preventDefault();` if there is no default behaviour you want to prevent: like clicking a div has no effect by default for example.

Comment: thank you very much, I have a doubt it is possible to activate another function to the options op2 and op3 while I click on option 1

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function on click, but the "this" refer to the function and not the element that is clicked. Pass the e as argument to the function and use e.currentTarget or just pas the this object to your function.

Answer (score 0):

the `this` keyword in your `changecolor` function is referencing the current scope not the element, you have to pass the element from the event handler function, like this:

```
function changecolor(element){
  $(element).css('background-color', 'white');
  $(element).css('border-top', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
  $(element).css('border-right', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
}
 $('#op1').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  changecolor(this);
});
```